# link_to_remote equivalent in rails 4

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I am upgrading from rails2.3.5 to rails4 and i am facing difficulty to convert link_to_remote into rails 4

```
link_to_remote("Retire", :url => { :action => :delete, :id => user.id },
               :condition => "confirm_retire(#{user.id})", :html => {:style => 'color: #CC0000;float:right;margin-right:8px;'})
```

I know that we need for this :remote => true with link_to like

```
link_to('Retire', {:action => :delete, :id => user.id},
               :condition => "confirm_retire(#{user.id})", :remote => true,
               :class => 'retire')
```

But i am facing problem with :condition => "confirm_retire(#{user.id})",

how to handle this ?, i did lot of research but not found any solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The condition option isn't supported by link_to. You could perform that check in a js file using a data attribute on the link element to provide a value for the condition.

```
link_to('Retire', {:action => :delete, :id => user.id},:remote => true, :class => 'retire', :data-user-retire => "your_condition")

$('.retire').on('click', function(){
  if ($(this).attr('data-user-retire') == "your condition") {
    return true;
  } else {
    $(this).append("some message")
    return false;
  }
});
```

This is just an example, you'll need to amend it for your requirements.